# Instagram ?__a=1 url doesn't display user picture on WordPress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, instagram, instagram-api

I decided to develop a new website based on my previous website.
Everything works well on my current site, but I can't get why I can't see the user profile picture on my new website.

I have the following code:

**functions.php**

```
function get_inst() { 
    $username = $_POST["login"];
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.instagram.com/$username/?__a=1");
    $acccount = json_decode($response, true);   
    echo $acccount['graphql']['user']['profile_pic_url'];
    die();
    }
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_inst', 'get_inst' );
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_inst', 'get_inst' );
```

**custom.js**

```
$('.buy .select_package .next').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    var current_price = $('.buy .select_package .nice-select .current .price').data("price");
    let package = $('.buy .select_package .nice-select .current').html()
    $('.buy .change_package .price').html(package)
    //let packagePrice = $('.buy .select_package .nice-select .current .price').text()
    let userName = $('.buy .select_package .user_name').val()
    $('.buy .change_package .user_name').text(userName)
     var price_we = $('.buy .payment .total_price .price').text('$'+cal_sell_price)
     //alert(price_we);
    $('.buy .select_package').hide()
    $('.buy .change_package').fadeIn(300)
    $('.buy .payment').removeClass('inactive')
    $("input[name='price']").val(cal_sell_price);
    $("input[name='count']").val($('.buy .select_package .nice-select .current .price').data("count"));
    $("input[name='login']").val(userName);

    var dataForAjax = "action=get_inst&login="+userName;
    var addressForAjax = myajax.url;
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:dataForAjax,
        url:addressForAjax,
        success: function(response){               
               $(".buy .change_package .icon img").attr("src", response);                
        }       
    });
```

**and that's how I display an avatar:**

```
<div class="icon">
<img data-src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/placeholder.png" alt="ig profile image" class="lozad">
</div>
```

UPD.

There're no errors in the console. But inside the code I see the following:

```
<img data-src="https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/themesmywebsite/assets/img/logo_mini.png" alt="ig profile image" class="lozad loaded" src="" data-loaded="true">
```

Comment: Where is `userName` defined, in your JS? What request goes out and what response comes back, when you look into your browser's network  tab? Do you see any error in your browser's developer console? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60872976/edit) to add all those details

Comment: Hi @blex much appreciate your response. I've edited my general message, thank you in advance